# Looking to monitor activity regarding connection attempts to closed ports on my system, what log file in should i look in? Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, tcp, log-files

I'm looking to monitor activity regarding connection attempts to closed ports on my system, as part of a server side [portknocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking) implemetation. However, I am confused about what log file in particular i should ask for this information. Checking my `\var\log` directory.

I found a pdf manual on the internet, "Implementing a Port Knocking System in C.pdf", and the part of the example we are concerned with is as below.

```
// INITIALIZE
memcpy(logfile, "/var/log/messages", sizeof(logfile)-1);
strcpy(password, getpass("Enter decryption password: "));
BF_set_key(&bfkey, sizeof(password), password);
logfileptr = NULL;
hosts = NULL;
```

I don't happen to have this log file `/var/log/messages` in my system. I've also tried ChatGpt and it says to try the `/var/log/syslog` in which I did not find any relevant information.

Comment: Your firewall log.